# Extend a striped volume in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hard-drive, dynamic-disk

Can **striped volumes** in Windows Server 2008 R2 be **extended**?

I have searched here on ServerFault and also on Google for an answer to this, and I can't seem to find an answer. Even the commercial tools I have looked at cannot do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  [Striped Volumes cannot be extended](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770938.aspx).

(Emphasis added.)

---

### Extend

Published: April 17, 2012

Updated: April 17, 2012

Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, ***Windows Server 2008 R2***, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista

Extends the volume or partition with focus and its file system into free (unallocated) space on a disk.

[...]

- On dynamic disks with simple or spanned volumes, a volume can be extended to any free space on any dynamic disk. Using this command, you can convert a simple dynamic volume into a spanned dynamic volume. ***Mirrored, RAID-5 and striped volumes cannot be extended.***

---

Answer (score -1):

[Extend a Simple or Spanned Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753058(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_WINUI)

Betrifft: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2

A spanned volume is a dynamic volume that consists of disk space on more than one physical disk. If a simple volume is not a system volume or boot volume, you can extend across additional disks. If you extend a simple volume across multiple disks, it becomes a spanned volume.

You can extend a volume only if it does not have a file system or if it is formatted using the NTFS file system. You cannot extend volumes formatted using FAT or FAT32.

Backup Operator or Administrator is the minimum membership required to complete the actions below.

Comment: Does not apply to the question whatsoever